# Why does delayed_jobs loop when it errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have had several occassions where delayed_jobs will be taking care of delivering 4 thousand emails, and if something errors in those emails ( for instance, if there's a nil a call ), then it will restart the entire process and attempt to send yet another 4000 emails. This will go on indefinately until I manually kill -9 the entire process.

It's happened so many times to me over the past few years in different applications, I'm curious if it has happened to anyone else. And what they did to overcome it.

Comment: You need to keep the track of the mails already sent..

Comment: Could you elaborate Mohit Jain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A delayed job is usually just a method that gets executed by a worker in a background process as opposed to during the main thread of your application (request lifecycle for a Rails app).

If you read the [documentation for delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) under "Gory Details" it states:

> On failure, the job is scheduled again in 5 seconds + N ** 4, where N is the number of retries.
>
> The default Worker.max_attempts is 25. After this, the job either deleted (default), or left in the database with “failed_at” set.
> With the default of 25 attempts, the last retry will be 20 days later, with the last interval being almost 100 hours.

It sounds like what you are describing is the way delayed_jobs was intended to function - if a job to send 4,000 emails fails after sending 3,000 of them, it just starts over again.  You will probably need to keep track of what has and hasn't been sent, so your job can loop over "unsent" emails (or whatever information is appropriate for your background process). That way when you send 3,000 emails, they get marked as "sent" and if your job fails, it will start over by loading the remaining 1,000 "unsent" emails and attempting to send them.

If you really don't want jobs to retry themselves on failure, you can add the following code to your project:

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
```

Comment: Brett, how would you recommend, integrating with delayed_job what emails were sent / not sent?

Comment: Trip: Depends on the structure of your app, how are you modeling the emails that are being sent?  Maybe you could ask another question with details about your structure?  My guess is I would aggregate the data being sent via email, store it in a new table with a boolean attribute `is_sent` that your job sets to true when it confirms it sent the email?  Perhaps after the job is 100% complete and you verify they're sent, you can delete them (if you are worried about the table growing too large).  Just a guess, very hard to say without knowing more about your app structure!

Comment: Hey Brett, just an FYI, I thought up adding the unique ID of the emails that are made to an array stored in the User model. It validates the presence of this id in the array before it send. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

We have a rule with delayed jobs for this exact reason - each job must be atomic. If the job fails for some reason (an exception, network error, etc) then the there must be no side-effects.

For jobs that just modify the database, the solution is easy - wrap the job in a transaction.

For jobs that interact with external services (sending email, hitting an API, etc) then we try to break each task into a separate job.

In your case we would create 4000 jobs, 1 to send each email. If some of them fail then they'll keep retrying without sending emails to everyone else over and over.

Comment: I wrap my jobs now in a `begin` and `rescue` statement with it finally ending in a `return true` statement. In this way, it never loops.

Comment: That will stop the job sending to people over and over, but if it throws an exception part way through then some emails won't be sent and you'll never know